# Subcontroller not working in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-modules

For my project I need to customize my code by adding subcontrollers in "Controllers" folder. 
Example:

In **controllers** I have added

```
controllers -> customer -> CustomerDetailsController.php
```

**Model:**

```
models -> customer -> Customer.php
```

**and Views:**

```
views -> customer -> customerdetails -> index.php, admin.php, _form.php .... etc
```

following is my `config/main.php` file:

```
'import'=>
array(
...
/* Loaded CustomerController model, view and controller */
                'application.controllers.customer.*',
                'application.controllers.models.customer.*',
...
)
```

And

**URL manager:**

```
'urlManager' => array(
                    'urlFormat' => 'path',
                    'showScriptName' => false,
                    'urlSuffix' => '/',
                    //'rules' => $params['url.rules'],
                    //Modified "rules" attribute for hiding index.php and added .htaccess in WebRoot
                    'rules' => array(
                        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                        array('customer/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'customer/<controller>/<action>'),
                    ),
                ),
```

Its not working for me.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CustomerDetails' not found
```

*Of-course I read about module but I don't want to implement module for this functionality and I would like keep that as an external entity.*

So how can I achieve this structure in entire project?

Comment: C'mon modules are cool:) This error looks like it can't find different class, not that controller. Have you try it with empty action? `CustomerDetails` while it should report `CustomerDetailsController`

Comment: Have you tried the url without 'customer' i.e `.../index.php/customerDetails/`? If yes does it work?

Comment: @topher: Yes I tried but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
'application.controllers.models.customer.*',
```

Are you sure that that's the path to you class file? It's probably something like this instead:

```
application.models.Customer
```

Right? I think that class names need to be Uppercase to be used in an alias. (The file itself is probably Customer.php and no customer.php).

Answer (score 0):

The last url rewrite rule should not be wrapped in an array i.e

```
'customer/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'customer/<controller>/<action>',
```

and not

```
array('customer/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'customer/<controller>/<action>'),
```

Also you should make sure you don't have a `CustomerController` in your main controller folder.